# Multiple authentication with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have an application that contains two fields : admin and candidate.

i have implemented spring security in the section candidate and it works but when i want to implement another security in the authentification for the admin, it doesn't work.

i have two authentification pages

there is my security code :

```
    <security:http  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" 
access-denied-page="/404.xhtml" >

    <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/candidat.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/aproposdemoi.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/chargermoncv.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/completermonprofil.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/maphotodeprofil.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/mescompetences.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/mesexperiences.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/meslangues.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/moncompte.xhtml" />
        <security:intercept-url access="hasAnyRole('candidat')"
        pattern="/supprimercompte.xhtml" />

    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
        login-page="/carrieres?login_error=1" always-use-default-target="true"
        default-target-url="/candidat.xhtml" />     
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/carrieres.xhtml" />   
    <security:remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret"/>



    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
        login-page="/adminzone?login_error=1" always-use-default-target="true"
        default-target-url="/tableaudebord.xhtml" />        
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/adminzone.xhtml" />   
    <security:remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret"/>
</security:http>




  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service id="jdbcMemoryAP"
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
          select email_candidat,mot_de_passe_candidat,enabled  
          from candidat where email_candidat=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.email_candidat, ur.autorite from candidat u, role_candidat ur 
          where u.id_candidat = ur.candidat and u.email_candidat =? " />
    </security:authentication-provider>     
</security:authentication-manager>


 <security:authentication-manager >
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service id="jdbcMemoryAP"
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
          select email_admin,mot_de_passe,enabled  
          from administrateur where email_admin=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.email_admin, ur.autorite from administrateur u, role_administrateur ur 
          where u.idAdmin = ur.administrateur and u.email_admin =? " />
    </security:authentication-provider>     
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: That's some messed up stuff you got there my friend. Firstly, don't you have some place where you can control who can access in Java code. You can use @PreAuthorize. What do you mean by fields? Are those different classes, tables? How have you implemented authentication or UserDetails, or in whatever way you have done it.

Comment: yes i have two tables admin and candidate, when i test only the security in the admin it works but when i want to make a security for both admin and candidates, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer for you, but it involves java code as well. Gimme like 15.

Comment: Okay thunk you. it doesn't matter the java code.

Comment: Welll, it should matter, as without that it wont work... :D

Answer (score 0):

So, Any time you have to login via two tables, both the Model classes of the tables should implement UserDetails. Per table, you will need one LoginService.

Security-applicationContext.xml :

```
// The 2 providers mentioned below are each for different datbase tables. Please //note, tables will be checked sequentially. 
  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
          <security:authentication-provider ref="hostAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="strengthInInteger you want, default 6" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
//Below is the first LoginServiceImpl, a java bean I have declared in //applicationContext.xml, not here.
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hostAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
//Below is the second Login implementation, a java bean I have declared in //applicationContext.xml, not here.
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="HostLoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Now,

// Notice that first LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService. This file is responsible to check if there is any student with the given username in db. If yes, then we build a User object which Spring-security understands, for which I will paste code after this file.

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private StudentDAO studentDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Student student = this.studentDAO.findStudentByUsername(username);
            if(student == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");}
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(student);
    }
}
```

Now, when user is found, then only we call this.

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Student userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        // Long id = userEntity.getId();
      //  boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT"));

        User user = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user;
        }
}
```

In a similar fashion, I have 2nd i.e HostLoginService :

```
@Transactional
@Service("hostuserDetailsService")
public class HostLoginService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private HostDAO hostDAO;
    @Autowired
    private HostAssembler assembler;

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_HOST");

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Host host = this.hostDAO.findHostByUsername(username);
        if(host == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");}
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(host);
    }
}
```

For brevity, I am avoiding the assembler for it.

Now you can see the roles are different. For proper redirection, you have to crearte  a controller method for the default-target-url of Spring-Security, check who is currently authenticated, admin or candidate by querying Spring-security. Then you can redirect.

If any doubt, let me know.